# Windows batch file to compile LaTeX

Tags: windows, batch-file, latex, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file to compile LaTeX documents. I've not found a solution to get it to compile every .tex file in the folder of the batch file. Is that easily accomplished?

```
SET STR=document

pdflatex "%STR%.tex"
bibtex "%STR%.aux"
pdflatex "%STR%.tex"
pdflatex "%STR%.tex"

DEL "%STR%.log"
DEL "%STR%.toc"
DEL "%STR%.aux"
DEL "%STR%.out"
DEL "%STR%.blg"
DEL "%STR%.bbl"

"%STR%.pdf"
```

Comment: OSX does not use DOS's batch files. It uses bash scripting. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Comment: See [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/5764).

Comment: You need `for %f in (*.tex) do ....`

Comment: `for %f in (*.tex) do pdflatex "%f"`